# Why SwingWorker? Why not just Thread or Runnable?

Tags: java, swingworker

What are the advantages of using `SwingWorker` instead of `Thread` or `Runnable`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thread and Runnable were part of Java 1.0; they're as good as they were back then.

The new concurrency classes distill all that's been learned about multi-threading since then (thank you, Doug Lea and others).  Writing multi-threaded code is terribly difficult.  The new concurrency classes, including SwingWorker, try to make that easier.

Start by noting the generics for strong typing.  There's a mechanism built in to publish and process both final and intermediate results.

It'd be possible to mimic these with Thread and Runnable, but SwingWorker has done it for you.

Comment: is SwingWorker really part of the new concurrency classes? I think it's part of the Swing API and the main reason for using it is because of the constraints regarding the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Comment: Not part of the concurrency package, but I'd consider it in the same spirit.   Could be wrong.

Answer (score 18):

I think the documentation of the [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is pretty good:

> An abstract class to perform lengthy
>   GUI-interacting tasks in a dedicated
>   thread.
>
> When writing a multi-threaded
>   application using Swing, there are two
>   constraints to keep in mind: (refer to
>   [How to Use Threads](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/threads.html) for more details):
>
> - Time-consuming tasks should not be run on the Event Dispatch Thread.
>     Otherwise the application becomes
>     unresponsive.
> - Swing components should be accessed on the Event Dispatch Thread
>     only.
>
> These constraints mean that a GUI
>   application with time intensive
>   computing needs at least two threads:
>   1) a thread to perform the lengthy
>   task and 2) the Event Dispatch Thread
>   (EDT) for all GUI-related activities.
>   This involves inter-thread
>   communication which can be tricky to
>   implement.
>
> SwingWorker is designed for situations
>   where you need to have a long running
>   task run in a background thread and
>   provide updates to the UI either when
>   done, or while processing. Subclasses
>   of SwingWorker must implement the
>   doInBackground() method to perform the
>   background computation.

surely you can do this using Thread, Runtime and SwingUtilities (`invokeLater`) but it's easier and probably less error prone using the SwingWorker class.

Answer (score 13):

SwingWorker takes care of some details, like UI updates while running the task, or after task finishes. These must be executed on Swing EDT thread. You can do it yourself, but it's too easy to do it wrong.

Answer (score 6):

`SwingWorker` encapsulates correct interaction with the event dispatching thread. `Runnable` doesn't.